# flutter upload image with multi_image_picker http

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-dependencies

I have this code trying to upload images with flutter
the code successfully picks multiple images from the gallery and displays it but it cant be uploaded successfully
here is the

"Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "multipart/form-data"."

```
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  String _error = 'No Error Dectected';

  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        );
      }),
    );
  }




  Future<void> uploadAssets() async {

    List<MultipartFile> multipart = List<MultipartFile>();

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(images[i].identifier);
      multipart.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath("file",path,filename: basename(path)));
    }
//    new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
//        filename: basename(imageFile.path));
//    List<ByteData> byteDataList = await Future.wait(images.map((Asset image) => image.getByteData()));
//
//    List<Uint8List> byteArrayList = byteDataList.map((ByteData byteData) {
//      ByteBuffer byteBuffer = byteData.buffer;
//      return byteBuffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteBuffer.lengthInBytes);
//    }).toList();


//    Map data = {
//       : multipart,
//      'description' : 'here',
//      'size': '7899'
//
//    };

    var res = await httpSend(multipart);
    print(res);
  }
  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = 'No Error Dectected';

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 300,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Example App",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }
 if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
      _error = error;
    });
  }




return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
            child:Container(

        child: Stack(
              children: [

 Visibility(

    visible:_pickvisiblee,
    child: Container(

    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0,180.0,0.0, 0.0),
//    child: Stack(
    child:Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: Text('Error: $_error')),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Pick images"),
          onPressed: loadAssets,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("upload"),
          onPressed: uploadAssets,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: buildGridView(),
        )
      ],
    ),
    ),
    ),


   ],
      ),
      );


    });
  }
}
```

I am trying to upload multiple images using http

```
Future httpSend(List<http.MultipartFile> params) async
{
  Map data ={
    'file':params
  };
  String endpoint = 'https://dynamicurl.com/api/uploadimage';
  final response= await http.post(endpoint, body: data,
    headers:{ "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data" } );
  List<dynamic> convertedDatatoJson = null;
  if(response.body.isEmpty){

    convertedDatatoJson =  null;
  }else{
    print(response.body);
    convertedDatatoJson =  jsonDecode(response.body);
  }
  return convertedDatatoJson;
}
```

here is the error
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "multipart/form-data".
i will like to see solution on how to upload multiple images, Firstly, convert List  to List, the error was as a result of my working.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the images_picker and Dio**

[link in pub dev IMAGES_PICKER](https://pub.dev/packages/images_picker)

[link in pub dev DIO](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

**Create a method to get List of images**

```
Future<List<Media>> getListImage() async {
return await ImagesPicker.pick(
  count: 3,
  pickType: PickType.image,
); }
```

**And create a method to upload file**

```
Future<void> uploadFile(String filePath) async {
    var filename = filePath.split("/").last;

    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: filename)
    });

    Dio dio = new Dio();
    var response = await dio.post(YOUR_URL, data: formData);

    print(response);
  }
```

**get the list of Media and upload**

```
var list = await getListImage();
    
list.forEach((element) async {
    
   await uploadFile(element.path);
    
});
```